# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) error !! not sure what to do

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

first I know this question has been posted alot of times on internet, but everytime people seem to give different solutions, and I tried a few and none worked for me.

so when I build my app I get this error :

```
Ld /Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TinyWings.app/TinyWings normal i386
    cd /Users/ahoura/Downloads/haqu-tiny-wings-e393aa3
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TinyWings.build/Objects-normal/i386/TinyWings.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lz -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TinyWings.app/TinyWings

ld: duplicate symbol _screenWidth in /Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TinyWings.build/Objects-normal/i386/pauseMenu.o and /Users/ahoura/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-dkfwmqscuzprkpappmtrrrahhgtu/Build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TinyWings.build/Objects-normal/i386/mainMenu.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

alot of people seem to say that it has something to do with a missing library or including a file in a special way!!!

NOTE I am using box2d, so C and C++ is mixed and the extension of the files are `.mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a missing library

You have defined the variable  screenWidth in both pauseMenu and mainMenu. It should only be defined in one of these.

Comment: thanks, that worked, but then when I use those vars, it says they are undefined ! how am I suppose to use those vars?

Comment: Let us see the code - and the commet re 'alot of people seem to say that it has something to do with a missing library or including a file in a special way!!!' seems to hav nothing to do with your issue

Comment: well the code is long, but I declared 2 vars like : `int screenWidth = 480;   
int screenHeight = 320;` in both files and just use them to place stuff around the screen, but if the code is really needed then I can put it in the question

Comment: and about the comment, tbh if you look around you will see most of them have missing libs :)

Comment: Yes but not for duplicate symbol - as this is only for something in more than once - the opposite of missung library